# I cant save a submit on database

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database, forms, save

i dont have errors but when i click on "ok" (the button for submit) nothing happen, my database dont change at all,
im doing my aplication like i press one button then all the pages that came further are already loaded, and i navigate between them using ajax and jquery, and im caling my form in one of this pages. it could be because of that? when i click on "ok" (submit button) it really dont react on console :S

**My form on a partial:** _impediments_risks.html.erb

```
 <div class="item-list">
  <%@solution = Solution.new(params[:solution])%>
  <% for i in (0..session[:project_impediments].size-1) %>
      <div class="item">
        <% impediment = session[:project_impediments][i][1] %>
        <div class="title">
          <span class="indicator"><%= impediment.priority.name %></span>
          <div class="description"><%= impediment.subject %></div>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
          <span class="title"><%= I18n.t 'text.solution' %></span>
          <ul>
            <% sol = ApplicationHelper.apply_filter(ApplicationHelper.Hash_DB(Solution.where('user_id IS NULL or user_id=?',session[:user])), ApplicationHelper.stem_phrase(impediment.subject.downcase)) %>
              <% sol.each do |s| %>
                <li><%= s %></li>
              <% end %>
                <li><b>NEW SOLUTION</b></li>
                <li>
                  <%= form_for(@solution)  do |f| %>
                    <%= render 'shared/error_messages' %>
                    <%= f.label :text %>
                    <%= f.text_field :text %>
                    <%= f.label :keywords %>
                    <%= f.text_field :keywords %>
                    <%= f.submit "Ok", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
                  <% end %>
                </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

**my controler** solutions_controller.rb

```
class SolutionsController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @solution = Solution.new
  end

  def create
    @solution = Solution.new(solution_params)
    if @solution.save
      #flash.now[:success] = "New Solution created!"
    else
      #Something
    end
  end

  private

  def solution_params
    params.require(:solution).permit(:text, :keywords)
  end
end
```

**My model:** solution.rb

```
class Solution < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :text, :keywords, :contar , :user_id

  before_save { |solution| solution.keywords = solution.keywords.downcase }

  default_scope -> { order('contar DESC') }  
  validates :text, presence: true, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }

  VALID_KEYS_REGEX = /\A([a-zA-Z]{3,})+(&|\|[a-zA-Z]{3,}+)*\z/i
  validates :keywords, presence:true, format: { with: VALID_KEYS_REGEX }
end
```

Comment: Post your `log information` when submitting the `form`.

Comment: And also try giving like this `<%= form_for(@solution, :url => { :action => "create",:controller => 'solutions' })  do |f| %>`

Comment: If you're using strong parameters you shouldn't have attr_accessible

Also if you're trying to downcase the keywords you should have `self.keywords = keywords.downcase`

Comment: pavan when i do that @solution it gives me an error undefined method for nilclass.
Baloo i comment it out in my code what u have said it doenst work too.

when i click on "ok" nothing happen on console :S 

Thanks u both for trying too help :)

Comment: For before save before_save { self.email = email.downcase} works for me. See the source html of form if it is formed correct. Does the page goes to some url.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your Solution object isn't being saved, presumably because it's failing validation.  Normally you would get some error messages in your form, for the failed @solution object, but you never see these because you overwrite @solution every time.

What should be happening is this:

a) making a new one
  - the new action makes a new @solution object and renders a page which uses `form_for @solution`

b) saving a new one
  - the create action makes a new @solution object using params[:solution].  If this fails to save, it renders out that same page which uses `form_for @solution`.  This page will usually show the errors for @solution.

When @Pavan says "try giving like this `<%= form_for(@solution, ...`", he's assuming that every action which renders out the page with this form will define `@solution`.  This is the standard railsy way.

Also, form_for will automatically send to either the create or update action, depending on whether it's a new object or not.  So, you shouldn't force it to create like you are doing with the url option.

I would change your code to be thus:

```
#controller
def create
  @solution = Solution.new(params[:solution])
  if @solution.save
    flash.now[:success] = "New Solution created!"
    #redirect wherever you go after the object is saved
  else
    render :template => <your page with the form partial>
  end
end

def update
  @solution = Solution.find(params[:id]) 
  @solution.attributes = params[:solution]
  if @solution.save
    flash.now[:success] = "Solution saved!"
    #redirect wherever you go after the object is saved
  else
    render :template => <your page with the form partial>
  end
end    

#view
...
 <%= form_for(@solution) do |f| %>
...
```

Comment: hi, i tried this , but it gaves me an error ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class)
thank you for trying to help

Comment: That's because @solution hasn't been defined when you're calling `form_for @solution`.  Is it defined in the action you're calling?

Comment: ok i've already defined it and the error was gone, but it seems that dont react when i press it on "ok". im doing my aplication like i press one button then all the pages that came further are already loaded, and i navigate between them using ajax and jquery, and im caling my form in one of this pages. it could be because of that? when i click on "ok" (submit button) it really dont react on console :S

Comment: Do you have any javascript errors reported in your console?

Comment: im sorry for just answering know.. i got only one sintax error, but i already have it before e do this step.. but it all works as before, but i still had the problem that i cant save on to db :